# Agregando productos de forma "masiva" con la API de Woocommerce es demasiado lento

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, batch

Estoy haciendo varios procesos con las taxonomías y productos comunicandome con el API de Woocommerce (solo para insertar registros), para consultar los registros que existen actualmente en la tienda lo hago directamente con una query en la base de datos para que sea más rápida la respuesta.

Aquí mi pregunta va más enfocada al tema de agregar y actualizar productos constantemente. Con las taxonomías no hay problema porque no superan ni los 200 registros y no se cambian muy seguido. El problema es en los productos, manejaré más de 10k.

Hice mi primera importación, tan solo eran 727 productos y demoró en este proceso 30 minutos... Utilicé el endpoint de products/batch, enviándole por grupos de 100 en 100 y aún así fue excesivo el tiempo que tomo tal proceso, ahora si quiero insertar los 10k de productos será de 5 horas más? Tengo que actualizar este proceso al menos 1 vez al día porque estos productos los obtengo desde un proveedor externo que nos provee una API.

Hay alguna forma de mejorar esto? Estoy buscando la forma de insertar directamente en la base de datos, pero es un tema que se me ha complicado porque el proceso(query) tiene que escribir en varias tablas, no se cuales realmente afecte una inserción en WP/Woo.

Algún consejo? buscar otra plataforma de ecommerce? no se.

De antemano agradezco sus aportes.

*Nota: Estoy desarrollando un backend para realizar todos estos procesos, no es directamente en WP.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se si te sirva, hace tiempo tuve un "detalle" parecido y realicé el mismo proceso en 3 pestañas, ósea que cada pestaña enviara unos 50-100 productos a la vez, es algo rudimentario pero te puede servir para una solución temporal.

Comment: @JosueVargas Gracias por la respuesta, suena bien esa solución temporal pero si es muy rudimentaria para este caso, el plan es ejecutar crons cada cierto tiempo para que se actualicé automáticamente sin necesidad de que el administrador lo haga.

Comment: Porque no divides los productos y realizas varios crons, osea todo automático pero divides el api de tus productos y cada cron hace su lista de productos. Igual esperaré a ver si alguien da una solución mas técnica porque si me interesa también. Saludos